# i want my jquery animation to wait till mouse enters for 2 second

Tags: jquery, timeout, jquery-animate, wait, mouseenter

1. I want my jquery-animation to wait till my mouse hovers/enters it for about 2 seconds. Otherwise, when i'm about to make the image bigger, things will become really chaotic.
   2.here's my code, which uses jquery to make a image bigger when it does a mouseenter:

   ```
    $('img').mouseenter(function(){

        $(this).animate({
               height: '+=40px',
           width: '+=40px'
           });

   });
   $('img').mouseleave(function() {    

       $(this).animate({
               height: '-=40px',
           width: '-=40px'
           }); 

   });
   ```

Comment: try the `.delay()` function http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `delay();`

```
  $('img').mouseenter(function(){
     var _width = $(this).width();
    var _height = $(this).width();
     $(this).stop().delay(2000).animate({
            height: '+=40px',
        width: '+=40px'
     });
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {    

    $(this).stop().animate({
            height: _height+'px',
        width: _width+'px'
        }); 


});

});
```

**UPdated**: http://jsfiddle.net/fwUMx/1165/

Comment: ok thanks :) with this, the problem is almost solved. there is only one problem left, when i quickly hover from one pic to another and stay for 2 seconds on the second pic, i don't want the first pic to enlarge. With the delay function, the two pictures will enlarge when i quickly move from one pic to another :/.

Comment: @breght understood, so you need to stop animation when mouseout

Comment: @breght try the code now i updated answer ;) i rly think it's what you need, you can also use css(); instead of animate , since you are not setting any animation delay in animate()

Comment: @breght you're welcome, if is that what you need, don't forget to check answer ;)

Comment: ok, i checked tha answer correctly ;) the  stop() function was the one i really needed. thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$('img').load(function() {
$(this).data('height', this.height);
}).bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
$(this).stop().animate({
    height: $(this).data('height') * (e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 1.5 : 1)
});
});
```

live demo http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/fwUMx/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.delay()` function here:

```
 $('img').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).stop().delay(2000).animate({
        height: '+=40px',
        width: '+=40px'
     });
 });
 $('img').mouseleave(function() {    
     $(this).stop().delay(2000).animate({
        height: '-=40px',
        width: '-=40px'
     }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .delay or setTimeout.

The below example using .delay

```
<p><button>Run</button></p>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>

$("button").click(function() {
      $("div.first").slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
      $("div.second").slideUp(300).fadeIn(400);
    });

div { position: absolute; width: 60px; height: 60px; float: left; }
.first { background-color: #3f3; left: 0;}
.second { background-color: #33f; left: 80px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/1118/